# accessing memory allocated with cudaMallocPitch

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I'm trying to create a 2d array in cuda and initializing it but failing miserably.
Here's my initialization kernel:

```
__global__ void initMap(float* map, size_t pitch, int w, int h, int numX, int numY){
int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
int idy=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
int i;
int j;
for (i=0; i<numX; i++){
    for (j=0; j<numY; j++){
        int idMC=idx+i;
        int idMR=threadIdx.y+j;
        if(idMC<w && idy+idMR<h){
             float* row=(float*)(map+idy+idMR*pitch);
             row[idMC]=0.5;
        }
    }
}

__syncthreads();
}
```

And here's how I allocate the array and call the initialization kernel in the main:

```
int width=map_size;
int height=map_size;
float* map;
size_t pitch;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&map, &pitch, width*sizeof(float), height));
int numT=32;
int numBX=(int)ceil((float)width/numT);
int numBY=(int)ceil((float)height/numT);
dim3 numBlocks(numBX, numBY);
dim3 numThr(numT, numT);
initMap <<<numBlocks, numThr>>> (map, pitch/sizeof(float), width, height, 1, 1);
cudaError_t err=cudaGetLastError();
if (err != cudaSuccess) 
    printf("Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is dividing the 2D array into 32x32 chunks, and assign each of those to a block which would then fill it with 0.5. However, when I try to either write the array to disk or access its elements from another kernel, I can see that there's many QNANs in there, so I guess I'm not filling up the whole array but rather missing some spots.

Comment: nevermind, I just forgot to put brackets around idy+idMR when doing the initialization.

Comment: This still isn't correct. While it might work, it only does so by accident. There is no guarantee that pitch is a round multiple of the allocation word size. The documentation for cudaMallocPitch includes the correct use of pitch in kernel code.

Comment: it's the one with the cast to (char*), right? I didn't use it as I wasn't really clear on what was being done there. Would you mind explaining it to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
__global__ void initMap(float* map, size_t pitch, int w, int h, int numX, int numY){
  int col = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
  int row = threadIdx.y + (blockDim.y * blockIdx.y);

  if ((row < h) && (col < w)){
    float *myrow = (float *)(((char *)map)+(row*pitch));
    myrow[col] = 0.5f;
}
```

This assumes the `pitch` parameter will be passed as a number of *bytes*, which is the way `cudaMallocPitch` sets it.  So the first thing we have to do is convert `map` to a `char` pointer.  Then we add the proper pitched offset to it based on the selected row, and convert the resultant pointer to a `float` pointer.  Then we index into the selected row using the `float` pointer.

Therefore your kernel call should be adjusted to:

```
initMap <<<numBlocks, numThr>>> (map, pitch, width, height, 1, 1);
```

Note that any "phantom" elements that are at indices greater than `w` on a row will not be initialized by this. They will contain garbage. But you should not be concerned about that or using those elements anyway.

When you copy this array back to the host,  you should use `cudaMemcpy2D`, which if set up properly will eliminate the phantom elements during the copy process back to the host, so there should be no garbage data in the host array. There are a number of questions on SO showing how to use cudaMallocPitch/cudaMemcpy2D properly.